# update key, values in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with lists as values:

```
foo = {5:[1,2,3]}
```

I want to add 1 to key as well as values and for that, I did this :

```
bar = {}
for k,v in a.items():
    z = []
    for i in v:
        z.append(i+1)
    bar[k+1] = z
```

Is there a better way to do this and does that method save runtime?

Excpected Result:

```
bar = {6: [2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: `{k+1: [i+1 for i in v] for k, v in foo.items()}`?

Comment: can you paste your expected output?

Comment: `{6: [2, 3, 4]}` isn't it?

Comment: this is fine. you could use dictionary/list comprehensions if you really want to, but essentially it's the same.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I timed the code and its 0.0 seconds, so my code is equally good?